# Critical tablespace usage UNDOTBS (96%)

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, tablespaces

This tablespace is in my case 8GB.
I'm on oracle 10g and  got critical warning:

```
Tablespace usage critical: UNDOTBS (96%)
```

I also executed this command:

```
select sum (bytes/1048576) MB
FROM
DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE    
tablespace_name = 'UNDOTBS' ;
```

It gives me 7625,625MB.

Could I extend this tablespace with this command:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE "UNDOTBS" ADD DATAFILE '/path/to/ts.db' SIZE 4194304000;
```

Can I do it on running system and wont I destroy anything?

Comment: Yes, you can do it while the DB is up

Comment: Could something go wrong? Would 12GB not be too much?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is fake alarm. the space UNDO tablespace is allocated differently then on other tablespaces. Oracle simply does not clean out old versions of block unless necessary. There are no real data in this tablespace.

You UNDO space was really full you would get ORA-01555 Snapshot too old, or other types of errors. Check the view v$undostat.

PS: what type of monitoring tool are you using?

Comment: I edited my post. Its custom checker, but also DBA_SEGMENTS  shows huge usage, so I guess it is true.

Comment: Not necessary, undo night be full of rollback segnents but still it might be ok